# ESP32 I2S in nanoFramework

Tags: esp32, adc, nanoframework, i2s

I'm trying to replicate a C++ project I found for [sampling sound data on the ESP32 using I2S](https://github.com/atomic14/esp32_audio), but using C# and nanoFramework.

In the ADCSampler.cpp file the following headers are loaded

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "driver/i2s.h"
#include "driver/adc.h"
```

nanoframework has the namespace [Windows.Devices.Adc](https://github.com/nanoframework/Windows.Devices.Adc) that I understand as more or less the same as `driver/adc.h`.

However I cannot find anything that is the same as I2S, there is a library for [I2C](https://github.com/nanoframework/System.Device.I2c)

The specific code I'm struggling with is:

```
void ADCSampler::configureI2S()
{
    //init ADC pad
    i2s_set_adc_mode(m_adcUnit, m_adcChannel);
    // enable the adc
    i2s_adc_enable(getI2SPort());
}
```

I have found that you can configure the ADC in nanoFramework as follow:

```
Configuration.SetPinFunction(35, DeviceFunction.I2S1_MDATA_IN);
```

and getting the ADC Channel

```
..
 AdcChannel _adcChannel7;
..
..
 _adc = AdcController.GetDefault();
 _adcChannel7 = _adc.OpenChannel(7);//GPIO pin 35 is adc channel 7
..
..
_mV = _adcChannel7.ReadValue();
..
```

but that is about as much as I can figure out.

I'm pretty new to microcontrollers and the ESP32 platform, so still learning a lot.

Have I missed something or is this still in the works?

Are there other options that can be used instead of I2S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting close!
A couple of clarifications:

1. despite the namespace looks similar it has to be added to the build. It's calling other functions that are required to exposed ADC features to the managed application.
2. In the current version, we are using pre-compiled ESP32 IDF libraries and I2S is not part of them. Meaning that you won't be able to use anything that's I2S related.
   Good news is that we'll be releasing a new version this week that includes I2S and a brand new C# library for I2S it's in the works and will be available shortly after.

So please follow our Twitter account or join the Discord community so you get notified of all that.

Comment: That is brilliant! I'll be ready to try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Espressif documentation on I2S might help
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html
Also, the examples might help https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/02605f1a31/examples/peripherals/i2s

Another option is using ESP with Arduino https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32
There is an I2S library used in many Arduino projects.

Comment: Thank you! All useful links. However I was specifically looking for the C# equivalent using the nanoFramework. I just notices there is a library out for it. https://github.com/nanoframework/System.Device.I2s